# How to save selection state in multipage results view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, web

I am trying to figure out how I can save selection state in a web app. To be more specific I am making some query interface that queries a mongo backend. The results are are rendered in a image gird type view with checkboxes on each image and a download button to download selected images.  Now, I am anticipating dealing with a lot of results for a given search. To handle this I am going to use paging. I am wondering how I would even save the selection state as I am flipping through paged results. I am totally new so if anyone can so much as provide an answer with some supporting information I can look into; that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to fetch the results on the next pages and append it into a separate section in the page rather than navigating away from the first page. This way the selected results are maintained as they are. You may need to do some calculation around your pagination and some toggling logic to show/hide divs when the pagers are clicked.

Useful link you could use (maybe ignoring the PHP/MySQL parts): http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-jquery-ajax-php/